# How can I add more tagged words to the Stanford POS-Tagger's trained models?

Tags: pos-tagger

I haven't found anything in the documentation about adding more tagged words to the tagger, specifically the bi-directional one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At present, you can't.  Model training is an all-at-one-time operation.  (Since the tagger uses weights that take into account contexts and frequencies, it isn't trivial to add new words to it post hoc.)

Comment: Hello professsor can we add new tagged sentences to the existing POSTagger models now.Now means you answered this question in 2011 .Its an honour to talk to you.

Comment: Would love to know about this too, this tagger give so many wrong result even for simple sentence My PRP$ cat NN drinks NNS milk NN    , that "drinks" should be VB

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround. It is ugly but should do the trick:

- build a list of "your" words
- scan text for these words
- if any matches found to POS tagging yourself (NLTK can help you here)
- feed it to Stanford parser.

FROM: http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cap5636/fall2011/nltk.pdf 
"You can also give it POS tagged text; the parser will try to use
your tags if they make sense. 
You might want to do this if the parser makes tagging
mistakes in your text domain."