# how to train the stanford LexicalizedParser to recognize new words as nouns?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to figure out how to train the stanford LexicalizedParser
( edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser )  to incorporate new nouns into its lexicon.

At first my goal was to take take an existing model and tweak it slightly, rather than creating a brand new model 
from a vast set of training examples.

the answer to this question suggests that is not possible > 
    [How can I add more tagged words to the Stanford POS-Tagger's trained models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570765/how-can-i-add-more-tagged-words-to-the-stanford-pos-taggers-trained-models)

Hopefully someone out there can put me on the right track as to how to do this.

As a concrete example of what i want to do, say i have the word 'researchgate' which i want to be treated as a noun when i parse 
sentences.  Currently, 'researchgate' is getting treated as different parts of speech, depending on its 
position.. but i want it identified as an 'NN' (noun).

Examples...

instead of this:

```
      (NP
        (NP (JJ recent) (NN activity))
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (PRP$ your) (JJ researchgate) (NNS topics)))))
```

i want this:

```
      (NP
        (NP (JJ recent) (NN activity))
        (PP (IN in)
          (NP (PRP$ your) (NN researchgate) (NNS topics)))))
```

and instead of this:

```
    (ROOT
      (FRAG
        (NP (NN subscription))
        (S
          (VP (TO to)
            (VP (VB researchgate))))))
```

i want this:

```
    (ROOT
      (NP
        (NP (NN subscription))
        (PP (TO to)
          (NP (NN researchgate)))))
```

I am currently using this model: models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz

I tried doing this >

```
    java -cp  stanford-parser.jar        
            edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser   -train  /tmp/train.txt
```

with the contensts of /tmp/train.txt as follows >

```
              (NP
                (NP (JJ recent) (NN activity))
                (PP (IN in)
                  (NP (PRP$ your) (JJ researchgate) (NNS topics)))))
```

I got a bunch of promising output, but then got this error >

```
    Error. Can't parse test sentence: [This, is, just, a, test, .]
```

So clearly i need to supply more examples than just the one i have in /tmp/train.txt.

Looking at the documentation there seems to be one promising method on 
LexicalizedParser  that I am considering trying... >

```
    public static LexicalizedParser getParserFromTreebank(Treebank trainTreebank,
                                                          Treebank secondaryTrainTreebank,
                                                          double weight,
                                                          GrammarCompactor compactor,
                                                          Options op,
                                                          Treebank tuneTreebank,
                                                          List<List<TaggedWord>> extraTaggedWords)
```

i am hesitant to jump in and try this because it seems tricky to get the Options right.
The doco says:
        options to the parser which MUST be the SAME at both training and testing (parsing) time in 
        order for the parser to work properly

so i might need guidance on how to extract the options used for 
edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz   perhaps it is

```
        edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.EnglishTreebankParserParams  ?
```

Also, maybe i want to add researchgate in as one of my extraTaggedWords  ?

I have the feeling i am on the right track but was hoping to get some advice before descending 
into a rat hole.

Thanks in advance !

```
chris
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted to stanford parser mailing list and I received an answer from John Bauer (thanks, John !)

*John Bauer 
2:09 PM (39 minutes ago)
to me, parser-user 
Unfortunately, you would need to start training from the beginning.  **There is no way to extend a current parser model.**
That feature is on "the list", but it's somewhere near the back, so don't hold your breath...
John*